# Can universe 6 saiyans turn into Oozaru?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

In universe 7 saiyans need a tale to turn into Oozarus. How about universe 6 saiyans? Do they have this transformation? Can Kyabe, Kale, Caulifla, kefura turn into Oozaru?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saiyan's from Universe 6 do not possess tails on account of the evolution process in their Universe. Cabba has no idea of it in the anime when Goku questions Cabba with regard to the same. Also, in the Manga Cabba knew of the tails and how they evolved past it

So technically, *they wouldn't be able to turn into Oozaru*